# Getting error when using Yii::app()->user->isGuest

Tags: yii, frameworks, yii-components

I am trying to know if a user is guest using Yii::app()->user->isGuest but I get the following notice:

```
Undefined property: CWebApplication::$user
```

Apparently the component user is not yet defined in the application, I would like to know the reason.

I had tried to check if the component is avalible via

```
if(isset(Yii::app()->user))
```

However it fails ¿How can I check if the user is a guest even when Yii::app()->user is not defined?¿Should I get this notice when using isGuest?

**EDIT**: I changed error_reporting directive to "E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT" I needed to move forward. Now I got this *fatal* error:

**Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in home/mario/projects/ciudad_wiki/yii/framework/web/auth/CWebUser.php on line 530**

### No  Time    Memory  Function    Location

1. 0.0005  235120  {main}( )   ../index.php:0
2. 0.0207  1548168 CApplication->run( )    ../index.php:13
3. 0.0207  1548352 CWebApplication->processRequest( )  ../CApplication.php:162
4. 0.0235  1725768 CWebApplication->runController( )   ../CWebApplication.php:135
5. 0.0272  2103464 CController->run( ) ../CWebApplication.php:276
6. 0.0279  2145872 CController->runActionWithFilters( )    ../CController.php:266
7. 0.0279  2145984 CController->runAction( )   ../CController.php:287
8. 0.0279  2146128 CInlineAction->runWithParams( ) ../CController.php:309
9. 0.0279  2146688 SiteController->actionIndex( )  ../CInlineAction.php:50
10. 0.0529  3875888 CController->render( )  ../SiteController.php:33
11. 0.0529  3876112 CController->renderPartial( )   ../CController.php:783
12. 0.0532  3877352 CBaseController->renderFile( )  ../CController.php:870
13. 0.0532  3877672 CBaseController->renderInternal( )  ../CBaseController.php:96
14. 0.0539  3918144 require( foo_dir/protected/views/site/index.php' )  ../CBaseController.php:127
15. 0.0705  4428584 CModule->__get( )   ../CBaseController.php:199
16. 0.0705  4428584 CModule->getComponent( )    ../CModule.php:104
17. 0.0723  4580360 CWebUser->init( )   ../CModule.php:388
18. 0.0736  4671144 CWebUser->getIsGuest( ) ../CWebUser.php:195
19. 0.0736  4671240 CWebUser->getState( )   ../CWebUser.php:279
20. 0.0736  4671320 CWebUser->getStateKeyPrefix( )  ../CWebUser.php:557

The trace is similar to the last one, Yii can't find anything in $_SESSION related to user component.

**EDIT #2:** I uploaded the trace with E_NOTICE on, here it is:
[PHP notice](http://jsfiddle.net/mmfmarin/RjZpM/1/embedded/result/)

**EDIT #3:** I updated php to 5.4 recently. When I run the application in a server with php 5.3 there is no problem, maybe there is a notice behind the scenes but not the fatal error I get with php 5.4. As bool.dev wrote: this is a complete guess.

Comment: can you check in your _config/main.php_ file if there is a `'user'` component under the `'component'` array?

Comment: @bool.dev yes, there is a user component: `'user'=>array(

             'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
             'class' => 'WebUser',
         ),`

Comment: you can either remove the `'class'` or change it to `'class'=>'CWebUser'` , or do you have a class you made yourself named `WebUser`?

Comment: @bool.dev I had a class WebUser, it's gone. I removed the class but nothing has changed.

Comment: this is a complete guess, can you try this: `Yii::app()->getComponent('session');// this will create session if not yet activated` and then call `Yii::app()->user;` or better try create component `Yii::app()->getComponent('user');`

Comment: It seems you are copying the config some other place, something missing in your configuration.

Comment: @onkarjanwa I don't see anything special in protected/config/main when I compare it to Yii blog demo. The only difference is this [plugin](https://github.com/Nodge/yii-eauth) configuration for facebook auth.

Comment: @bool.dev I added   `Yii::app()->getComponent('session');
  <br>echo '<pre>'; var_dump(Yii::app()->getComponent('user')); echo '</pre>';` to views/layout/main.php but nothing changed.

Comment: Try adding `user` to `preload`.

Comment: @BorisBelenski Thank you but it didn't worked.

Comment: not an expert, but did you check if session component is getting created after getComponent('session') ? and what do you think is happening? any guesses? this is weird, have you asked in the yii forum? if not please ask there too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I ran a massive replacent that corrupted the framework. I realized the problem was yii directory because I don't track it with git, when I set up a new production environment, in a virtual machine, everything was fine again and the only difference was the framework directory. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score -1):

I was getting a similar problem when pulling a master branch from GitLab on a virtual machine. It looked like it couldn't find the user and/or session component.

I've been around this for days, however I found that adding this in the first line of index.php of Yii (right after "

```php
error_reporting("E_ALL & ~E_STRICT");
```